# If folders don't exist in URI path, file_save_data() fails

Tags: files

I am programmatically importing images and saving them via file_save_data();

```
$fileContentsPath = 'http://mypathtofile.com';
$uri = 'public://myfolder/mysecondfolder/filename.jpg';
$image = file_get_contents($fileContentsPath);
$file = file_save_data($image, $uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

When I run this I get the following error: The specified file temporary://fileJ4LL4o could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.

I am pretty sure my temporary directory is configured correctly and the files folder is assigned to the apache user.

If I go into the files directory and make the directories (myfolder/mysecondfolder) via command line and rerun it works correctly.

So the problem is that if the folders don't exist from the $uri path, it fails instead of creating the folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a function that creates the folders if needed. I copied what Patrick had [here](http://www.patrickjwaters.com/blog/2013-08-22/drupal-7-how-programmatically-download-files-optionally-save-them-managed-files-save).

```
/**
 * Download external file.
 *
 * @param string $url       Full url to file to download.
 * @param string $uri       Drupal uri of where to save file
 *                          public://archive/test.pdf.
 * @param int $save_mode    File save mode from drupal core
 *                          Ex: FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE.
 *
 * @return mixed $new_file  The file object.
 */
function xcms_import_download_external_file($url, $uri, $save_mode = FILE_EXISTS_RENAME, $manage_file = TRUE) {

  $url_info = parse_url($url);
  $url_path_info = pathinfo($url_info['path']);

  // This helps with filenames with spaces
  $url = $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host']  . $url_path_info['dirname'] .'/'. rawurlencode($url_path_info['basename']);

  // Need to remove the filename from the uri
  $uri_target = file_uri_target($uri);
  $uri_scheme = file_uri_scheme($uri);
  $uri_path_info = pathinfo($uri_target);
  $directory = file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize($uri_scheme . "://" . $uri_path_info['dirname']);

  if (file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
    $drupal_result = drupal_http_request($url);
    if (!empty($drupal_result->data)) {
      $path = file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize($uri);
      if ($manage_file) {
        $new_file = file_save_data($drupal_result->data, $path, $save_mode);
      }
      else {
        return file_unmanaged_save_data($drupal_result->data, $path, $save_mode);
      }
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message("Error downloading file, no data recieved for " . $url);
      return FALSE;
    }

    $new_file->display = 1;
    return (array)$new_file;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In drupal 8.7.0 and above (Drupal 9), `file_prepare_directory()` is deprecated.

Instead, use `FileSystemInterface::prepareDirectory()` : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystemInterface.php/function/FileSystemInterface%3A%3AprepareDirectory/8.8.x

In my case, I did :

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface $file_system */
$file_system = \Drupal::service('file_system');
$directory = 'temporary://exports/';
$file_system->prepareDirectory($directory, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```

Answer (score 8):

I Noticed Similar issue while saving files using

```
 file_save_data();
```

In Drupal 8.

First I gave only first level directory to save the file as

```
$file = file_save_data($object->vertex_data, 'public://vertex_data.txt', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

This worked fine.

But when I tried saving the file inside a subfolder as

```
$file = file_save_data($object->vertex_data, 'public://objects/vertex_data.txt', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

it gave me the following Error :

```
File temporary://fileh1Gpl2 could not be moved/copied because the destination directory public://objects/ is not configured correctly.
```

The Solution for this is simple. Just use [file_prepare_directory()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/file_prepare_directory/8.2.x);

```
$directory = 'public://objects/'
file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
$file = file_save_data($object->vertex_data,  $directory . 'vertex_data.txt', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

This, first creates the folder if it does not exists and then proceeds to save the respective file.